# Yii2 Redactor is not loaded after ajax/pjax request

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, pjax, redactor

I use redactor for editing comment. There are multiple redactors since there are multiple comments.  Most of the time, redactor is loaded, but sometimes the redactor is not loaded and only generate normal text editor.

These comments are loaded after Pjax Request

My code:

```
    <?= \yii\redactor\widgets\Redactor::widget([
        'name' => 'comment',
        'value' => \yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($comment),
        'clientOptions' => [
            'imageUpload' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/redactor/upload/image']),
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

You have to put ID :)

```
<?= \yii\redactor\widgets\Redactor::widget([
        'id' => 'edit_redactor_' . $comment_id,
        'name' => 'comment',
        'value' => \yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($comment),
        'clientOptions' => [
            'imageUpload' => \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/redactor/upload/image']),
        ],
    ]) ?>
```